# on Scroll, value of Spinner resets in Android. How to avoid it

Tags: android

I have a spinner which contains dynamic Array data. When I select the value in spinner and scroll down and again scroll up, the value resets, what could be the reason behind this, how can i avoid it. Below is my code :

```
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(UserSurveyAdapter.this);

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                int arraysize = oi.getOptList().size();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Size ==" +arraysize );
                for (int k = 0; k <arraysize; k++) {   
                    if(k == 0){
                        list.add("");
                    }else{
                        list.add(oi.getOptList().get(k));
                    }

                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list) {

                    @Override
                       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                               View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                               if (position == getCount()) {
                                   ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                                   ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
                               }

                               return v;
                           }       

                           @Override
                           public int getCount() {
                               return super.getCount()-1;            // you don't display last item. It is used as hint.
                           }

                   };


                   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
                   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                   spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());        //set the hint the default selection so it appears on launch.
                   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Where have you implemented Spinner ? In list ? If I am not wrong, I think you have implemented Spinner in AdapterView. WHICH IS, INFACT, WRONG..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see selected/changed data in spinner then,

First, make an array/arraylist of values if spinner.
Second, put a boolean value in that, like active(true or false).
Third, when you select that value from spinner change default value of active.

Note: This array have to be passed in your adapter. So, getView get this array's value always.

for your reference, check this example, [ListView](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)